# Non-trivial metric space $X$ with all of $C(X)$ uniformly continuous.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, uniform-continuity, uniform-spaces

Is there a metric space $X$ such that any $f\in C(X)$ is uniformly continuous, but there is a metric space $Y$ and $g:X\to Y$ which is continuous but not uniformly continuous?

If $X$ is compact or discrete then it never satisfies this.

Indeed, if $X$ is compact then any continuous $g:X\to Y$ is uniformly continuous. If $X$ is discrete and $\inf_{x\neq y} d(x, y)>0$ then any $g:X\to Y$ is uniformly continuous. If $\inf_{x\neq y}d(x, y) = 0$ then we can find $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ which isn't uniformly continuous.

For further context: This is a stronger question than if two functors on uniformizable spaces, one which gives a uniformizable space its fine uniformity, and second which gives it an induced uniformity, coincide.

Comment: A metric space $X$ so that any $f \in C(X)$ is uniformly continuous is of a special form, something like a discrete part and a compact “core”. So probably no such $X$ can exist.

Comment: What is that last functor? There is AFAIK no functorial way to assign a uniformity to a uniform Isabel space, except the fine uniformity, which is special…

Comment: Oh. We assign to a uniformizable space $X$ the coarsest uniformity for which all continuous functions $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ are uniformly continuous. I thought there might be an example among metric spaces.